# iOS 3D Touch menu not working after language change

Tags: ios, language, multi-touch

When I switch language, Safari's and Calculator's 3D menu is not working. (Message's one does however.) When I open these apps and background them, it works again.
Is there an official bug report for that?

Answer (score 1):

Users have already reported this bug with ID 22314248 within their [system](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for developers: the error appears only, if you add the menu programmatic. If you set it from `info.plist`, it works.